# Ruby (+=) Add AND assignment operator and initial nil value

Tags: ruby

Is there a better (ruby way) to achieve the following:

```
if a.nil?
  a = 1
else
  a += 1
end
```

Comment: What if *a* is true or false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `a` can ever only be `nil` or an integer, then

```
a = a.to_i + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`a = (a || 0) + 1` also works  .

Answer (score 1):

### Be More Idiomatic

If you know that *a* will never be true, false, or something else that can't be coerced to an Integer, you can use this Ruby idiom:

```
a ||= a.to_i.succ
```

### Be More Robust

A more robust construct might be:

```
a = a.respond_to?(:succ) ? a.succ : 1
```

It's not as pretty, but it will be more likely to "do the right thing" in your case. You could also ask if `a.is_a? Integer`, but that fails to take advantage of duck typing in the event that you have an object that is incrementable but isn't really an Integer.

There's always more than one way to do something like this, so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = a ? a+1 : 1
```

...............

Comment: Okay, okay, it can be made more succinct anyway.

Comment: VII, I see absolutely nothing wrong with that. In terms of read-speed, it may be the fastest. +1